# PhoneGap and XSockets.NET "Hello World" JavaScript Failed

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, xsockets.net

I created the following ‘hello world’ HTML file using Phonegap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/XSockets.latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    function init()
    {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() 
    {       
        document.write("Device Ready!");            

        try
        {
            var ws;
            ws = new XSockets.WebSocket('ws://joinaspot.com:4509/Generic');

            //ws.publish("myTopic",{myMessage: 'hello world!'});                    

            ws.onopen = function(connection)
            {
                document.write("<br/>WebSockets Ready!<br/>"); 
                document.write(JSON.stringify(connection));
            };

            ws.on(XSockets.Events.onError, function (err) 
            {
               document.write("<br/>Error: " + err);
            });
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            document.write("<br/>Exception Caught: " + e);
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="init();"> 
    </body>
</html>
```

When I ran this locally (Chrome on Windows 7) I received the following output:

```
Exception Caught: InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state
```

Which is perfect because I know that I am forcing a ‘publish’ before a connection has been established, and I do this so I can receive an error.

When I ran as a Phonegap Android Application (apk) deployed to my Samsung Galaxy S3, I received the following output:

```
Exception Caught: Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
```

When I ran this on the emulator I received the error:

```
Exception Caught: InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
```

I then removed the line “ws.publish("myTopic",{myMessage: 'hello world!'});”  and ran it again on the emulator and received the following output:

```
Device Ready!
WebSockets Ready!
```

which is exactly what I want to see. I then deployed to my android phone and the only output I get is:

```
Device Ready!
```

Has anyone run an app with XSockets.Net as a Phonegap package? Are there any special tricks/configurations to get this working? I know that in Phonegap config.xml you must add URLs to be access by the app, so I added the following entries to config.xml:

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
<access origin="http://joinaspot.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="ws://joinaspot.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://joinaspot.com:4509/Generic"/>
<access origin="ws://joinaspot.com:4509/Generic"/>
```

I still only receive “Device Ready!” when running the app on my phone. I currently only have this working on the emulator.

**EDIT:** I removed all access tags in `my-app\www\config.xml` and only used:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

however my app still only shows `Device Ready!`. If everything works, then I expect `Websockets Ready!` in the output as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!